# Why does std::vector::front has two definitions? (C++)

Tags: c++, vector

I'm a C++ newbie. Could you tell me why std::vector::front has two definitions, how they are different, and how each of them is called?

The function seems to have two definitions,

- reference front();
- const_reference front() const;

I noticed these two definitions, when I looked up the function on the Web. The following two web sites seem to say the same two definitions.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/front/

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front

Comment: It's to keep const correctness. One for non consts and one for consts.

Comment: @GillBates: your name has made me chuckle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const` version is used by a `const` `this` pointer due to *overload resolution*. It would not be sensible if a non-`const` object were returned, since then you could hack round the `const`ness.

The non-`const` version is used by a non-`const` `this` pointer. You get back an object that you can modify.

We call this *const correctness*.

Comment: Thank you, @FaceyMcFaceFace .